# Python Code not executing next line of code in a while Statement

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, break, continue

I'm trying to build a calculator, and when a result is given it's not entering the next "if" statement

Here is my code:

How can I make sure after I get an answer  it goes to the next line of code and either continue the While loop or exit the while look?

```
print('Hello, this will be our first calculator')

symbol = input('Do you want to add, multiply, or divide a number? Please use symbols like *, -, +, /: ')
num1 = float(input('What is the first number?'))

num2 = float(input('What is the second number?'))

def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1*num2

def subs(num1, num2):
    return num1-num2

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2


while True:
    if symbol == '*':
        print(mul(num1, num2))
        cont = input('Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N ')
        if cont == 'Y' or 'y':
            continue
        elif cont == 'N' or 'n':
            break
    elif symbol == '-':
        print(subs(num1, num2))
        cont = input('Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N ')
        if cont == 'Y' or 'y':
            continue
        elif cont == 'N' or 'n':
            break
    elif symbol == '+':
        print(add(num1, num2))
        cont = input('Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N ')
        if cont == 'Y' or 'y':
            continue
        elif cont == 'N' or 'n':
            break
    elif symbol == '/':
        if num2 != 0:
            print(div(num1, num2))
        else:
            print('Cannot divide with 0, you will break the world')
        cont = input('Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N ')
        if cont == 'Y' or 'y':
            continue
        elif cont == 'N' or 'n':
            break
    else: 
        break
```

Comment: just pull the three lines `symbol = input("...")` and the next two lines where you ask for the operation and the numbers inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

The way you've implemented it now, the variables `symbol`, `num1` and `num2` are still set when you enter the next iteration in the while loop and thus are used to determine which calculation is performed.

To get around this, you need to ask for these inputs inside the loop, meaning your loop should start with the following lines:

```
while True:
    symbol = input('Do you want to add, multiply, or divide a number? Please use symbols like *, -, +, /: ')
    num1 = float(input('What is the first number?'))
    num2 = float(input('What is the second number?'))
```

You then don't need to ask for these values beforehand anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Now I'm getting the following 

Do you want to add, multiply, or divide a number? Please use symbols like *, -, +, /: *
What is the first number?5
What is the second number?6
30.0
Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N n
Do you want to add, multiply, or divide a number? Please use symbols like *, -, +, /: 

when i put n it should exit out, do you know why is not doing that?

Comment: Basically, I want to confirm why this while True:
    if symbol == '*':
        print(mul(num1, num2))
        cont = input('Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N ')
        if cont == 'Y' or 'y':
            continue
        elif cont == 'N' or 'n':
            break

is not breaking when I enter N or n

Comment: I was able to figure it out! my keyboard was entering m as n and vice versa for some apparent reason lol. Everything is good!